# Iterating of piecewise function

Tags: iteration

I have this piecewise function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x(1.5-0.5x) \quad\text{if $x\le0.5$},\\
x(0.5+0.5x) \quad\text{if $x>0.5$}.
\end{cases}
$$
How can I calculate iterated functions for it?

Comment: `f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{x(1.5-0.5x),x<=0.5},{x(0.5+0.5x),x>0.5}}]; {f[2],f[f[2]],f[f[f[2]]]}` returns {3.,6.,21.}. And `{Nest[f,2,1],Nest[f,2,2],Nest[f,2,3]}` returns the same.

Comment: @Bill that's what `NestList` is for: `NestList[f, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the three built-in iteration function that will be interest to you are [`FixPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixPoint.html), [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) and [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html).

`FixPoint` and `Nest` both return only the final iterate. `NestList` returns a list of the initial value plus all the iterates. `FixPoint` and `Nest` are very similar, except `FixPoint` checks for converges and stops if it finds it. `Nest` makes no such check and will always perform the full iteration.

These function don't care whether the function they are iterating is piecewise or not.

Examples

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x (1.5 - 0.5 x), x <= 0.5}, {x (0.5 + 0.5 x), x > 0.5}}]
FixedPoint[f, 3/4, 500] // N
```

> `0.506723`

```
Nest[f, 3/4, 500] // N
```

> `0.506723`

```
NestList[f, .75, 10]
```

> `{0.75, 0.65625, 0.543457, 0.419401, 0.541153, 0.417, 
>   0.538556, 0.414299, 0.535626, 0.411261, 0.532324}`